# Rails dealing with single and double quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem in dealing with single quoted characters in en.yml, in my erb file I have a line of code,

`<input type="text" class="something" id="myUsername" placeholder='<%= I18n.t("entries.email") %>' value="<%= user.email%>">`, and corresponding yml is,

```
entries:
  email: "Entrer le nom d'utilisateur"
```

The problem here is that the string after apostrophe (d') gets truncated, I could resolve it by using double quoted string for placeholder, that way it worked, but is that a good solution, can someone suggest me a better way to deal with this.

Note: Tried escaping single quote but didn't work for some reason.

Comment: What's wrong with using a double quoted string for placeholder? If that works, just do it.

Comment: @joshua.paling Yea it works, but I am just assuming whether can we make use of %q in this situation.

Comment: @ALLANXAVIER   Why are you putting effort on something which other already did. Use Rails helps on this cases. Don't need to do the way you are trying to adjust. Make your code and life easy. :)

Comment: Hi Allan can you please post the output html that you are getting by inspecting the element on your browser

Answer (score 1):

Write it using [`text_field_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag) helper :

```
<%= 
   text_field_tag "user[email]", user.email, id: "myUsername",
    placeholder: I18n.t("entries.email"), class: "something"
%>
```

It is easy to use.

Comment: Your solution works but for me the problem here is I have to maintain the html code. Is there a way to make use of %q in this situation, that's something I am looking for.

Comment: @ALLANXAVIER The Rails helper will render exact HTML you are trying to maintain. Again, make your life easy, that's why we use Rails.

Comment: You are just doing completely wrong. Your HTML is using `ERB`, and you are not taking the advantage of it. Think twice, what I am trying to tell you.

Comment: I understand that but I can't go that way due to some other reasons what I looking for is to use %q

Comment: @ALLANXAVIER then remove the `.erb` tag, and keep the `.html` only. And see if `<%= ..%>` works for you.. BTW, what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @ALLANXAVIER I just tested your code and it seems working fine

Comment: @ArupRakshit Actually it's a ejs file, sorry to mislead you, what I am trying to achieve is that the string in fr.yml is getting truncated, I am able to view only till  Entrer le nom d, where as the actual string is "Entrer le nom d'utilisateur", I want to find out a way to display the entire string and wish to do it through %q, I tried out different ways to place the %q in front of placeholder but no luck, this way we don't have bother about the single quotes and double quotes that gets in the way.

Comment: I don't know what is `.ejs` file..Sorry :(